# How to compare the elements of the list and matrix and eliminate spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, matrix

I have a matrix(l2) and a list(l1).
I want to check if any word of the list(elements in l1) are in the matrix or not. And If there is, the algorithm should attach the separated words. For example,

```
l1=['soheila','mahin','rose','pari']
l2=[['so he ila ha','soh e i la h a','so h eil a ha'],
    ['ma h in','m ah in','mahi n'],
    ['r os es', 'ro se s','ros e s'],
    ['pa ri sa','pari s a','p ar i sa']]
```

and my desire output is:

```
output=[['soheila ha','soheila h a','soheila ha'],
    ['mahin','mahin','mahin'],
    ['roses', 'rose s','rose s'],
    ['pari sa','pari s a','pari sa']]
```

As you see in this example, the spaces between the character of the words in the matrix and the list are deleted but the rest of words no.
I use this code to delete all of the spaces between characters in the matrix:

```
import numpy.core.defchararray as np_f

l3=list()
l3=l2

new_data = np_f.replace(l3, ' ', '')
#print(new_data)

for count_i, value in enumerate(l2):
    result = [i for i in l3[count_i] and new_data[count_i] if l1[count_i] in i]  
    print(result)
```

But I don't know how to code the condition of the problem to produce the output matrix. I search alot and I know I can do it by using `equalsIgnoreCase` in Java but I'm at the beginner level of Python and have weaknesses. Could you help me to solve this problem and produce the output matrix?

Comment: Python's equivalent to Java's `String.equalsIgnoreCase(s1, s2)` is `s1.lower() == s2.lower()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Pardon, what about the condition? How should I compare the strings in the list and the matrix by this code? @TDk

Comment: I mean deleting the space of the word in the matrix. I've explained badly : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it like this**

```
l1=['soheila','mahin','rose','pari']
l2=[['so he ila ha','soh e i la h a','so h eil a ha'],
['ma h in','m ah in','mahi n'],
['r os es', 'ro se s','ros e s'],
['pa ri sa','pari s a','p ar i sa']]


l = [[ word + " "  + subword.replace(' ', '').replace(word, '') for subword in sublist if word in subword.replace(' ', '')]  for sublist in l2 for word in l1]

result = list(filter(None, l))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

> [['soheila ha', 'soheila ha', 'soheila ha'], ['mahin ', 'mahin ', 'mahin '], ['rose s', 'rose s', 'rose s'], ['pari sa', 'pari sa', 'pari sa']]

Comment: Wow.. Such a good solution. Only one of the elements was different so I can work on my program to produce the best l2 matrix and then use your solution to produce the output. Thank you a lot. It was very very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind my asking why not just split each index in the L2 list via the spaces:

```
L3=[]
For i in L2:
L3.append("".join(i .split(" ")))
```

Then check normally if a work in `L1` is in `L3`
Haven’t checked if this would work but this is what I thought of, off the top of my head.